# Why does Bender fall in love?

Tags: futurama

In the episode Bendless Love, why does Bender fall in love with the female bending unit if robots are supposed to not have feelings?

Comment: Is your belief that robots don't have feelings based on a general knowledge of robots in movies, TV and literature or is it based on something mentioned in Futurama itself?

Comment: @stevvve From [*Anthology of Interest 2*](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:Anthology_of_Interest_II), "being a robot's great, but we don't have emotions and sometimes that makes me *very sad.*"

Answer (score 4):

What are you talking about? Bender has loads of feelings! I've seen my fair share of angry and crying robots in Futurama.

Just off the top of my head:

1) When Bender is sad because he is being judged for secretly wanted to be a folk singer (Bendin' in the Wind)

2) When Bender falls in love with Amy in Proposition Infinity

3) When Bender is angry....... pretty much 90% of the show.

4) When Bender loves and sacrifices everything for his son, Ben. (Bots and the Bees)

5) When Bender has an existential crisis when he finds out he is defective and dies when his body does (Lethal Inspection)

Also, what about Calculon? You need real emotion to have such an unholy... acting... TALENT!

Answer (score 3):

Robots in Futurama are shown many times to have feelings:

- Love, as per your question.
- Anger, which Bender has shown many times.
- Friendship, from Bender to Fry.
- Vengeance, from a number of robots on humans.
- Disappointment, the Robot Devil on a number of times.

So I think Bender falling in love is just one more example of these feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Bender may seem to have fallen in love with several female (and the occasional male) characters over the series, but he is a total player at heart and has always ended up breaking off his romantic relationships in one way or another. As for why Bender is able to express his emotions, I can not recall an instance in the series where robots are prohibited from having feelings so he isn't breaking any rules by doing so.